# Error 43 while knitting a markdown to pdf in a R project created on mac and run on Windows

Tags: windows, r, knitr, pandoc, markdown

I created a R project which outputs some plots to pdf using rmarkdown::render with an .Rmd file.

I shared the folder when the R project and all the relative files are kept to a colleague using Google Drive. I created the project on a Mac and the colleague is using Windows.

When I knit the .Rmd file to pdf on my mac I have no problem.

When I run the code on his Windows I get this error:

```
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS Plot_per_DPUO.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output "Grafici Professioni/Periodo apr-14 ott-15 test/DH ALLERGOLOGIA - SAN PAOLO.pdf" --template "C:\Users\lucilla.rava\Documents\R\win-library\3.1\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable "geometry:margin=1in" 
pandoc.exe: Could not find image `Grafici%20Professioni\Periodo%20apr-14%20ott-15%20test\DH%20ALLERGOLOGIA%20-%20SAN%20PAOLO_files/figure-latex/set-options-1.pdf', skipping...
pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source.
! I can't find file `C:/Users/LUCILL'.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
<*> C:/Users/LUCILL~
                    1.RAV/AppData/Local/Temp/tex2pdf.3172/input.tex
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
<*> C:/Users/LUCILL~
                    1.RAV/AppData/Local/Temp/tex2pdf.3172/input.tex
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on C:/Users/LUCILL~1.RAV/AppData/Local/Temp/tex2pdf.3172/tex
put.log.

 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

The temporary files for the plots seem not to be found. My educated guess is that there could be some problem with separating hashes in the paths. In the error I see a mix of Unix and Windows ones \ /.

Also there is this part in which the user name in the path is strange:

```
<*> C:/Users/LUCILL~
                    1.RAV/AppData/Local/Temp/tex2pdf.3172/input.tex
```

while it should be lucilla.rava.

Here's the code from which I call render():

```
render.report <- function(type = 1, test = F) {
test <- if (test) ' test' else ''
months.vec <- get.months(unique(Data$Periodo))
 months.vec <- format(months.vec, '%b-%y')
if (type == 1) folder.name <- 'Grafici Generali'
 else if (type == 2) folder.name <- 'Grafici Professioni'
 else if (type == 3) folder.name <- 'Grafici Indicazioni'
folder.path <- file.path(folder.name, sprintf('Periodo %s %s%s', months.vec[1], tail(months.vec, 1), test))
dir.create(folder.path, recursive = T, showWarnings = F)
for (UO in unique(Data$UO)) {
 render('Report template.Rmd', clean = T, output_file = file.path(folder.path, sprintf('%s.pdf', sub(pattern = "/", replacement = ' ', UO, fixed = T))))
 }
}
```

And this is the .Rmd:

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
- \usepackage{tikz}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usetikzlibrary{calc}
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
- \renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
- \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
- \pagenumbering{gobble}
---

\newcommand{\header}[1]{
 \thispagestyle{empty}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
 \definecolor{head.col}{HTML}{5B9BD5}
 \draw let \p1 = (current page.west), \p2 = (current page.east) in
 node[minimum width=\x2-\x1, minimum height=2cm, draw, rectangle, fill=head.col, anchor=north west, align=center, text width=\x2-\x1] at ($(current page.north west)$) {\Large\bfseries #1};

 \end{tikzpicture}
}

```{r set-options, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE, fig.width=9, fig.height=7, results='asis'}
# if (type == 1) create.dpuo.graph(UO, T)
# if (type == 2) create.dpuo.prof.graph(UO, T)
# if (type == 3) create.dpuo.indc.graph(UO, T)

create.graph(UO, type, T)

create.table(UO, type)
````

We need the project to work both on my computer and on his.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Avoid strange characters in file names, including directory names. Especially if you need it to work cross-platform. I wouldn't use them even on a single platform as they are a lot of pain for no benefit at all. On two platforms... just don't. [Spaces are definitely weird in the relevant sense. Note that it is turning them into `%20` (e.g. `Grafici%20Professioni`.]

Comment: Also, it is using hard-coded full paths. I doubt Windows has a top level directory `Users` or a directory under it. That `/Users/<username>` stuff is a Mac directory. Even turned into Windows syntax, it ain't going to work unless you replicate the Mac directory tree appropriately. Make sure all files are in a single directory, if possible. And don't use full path names.

Comment: Ok for the spaces, I'll try using underscores. Regarding the paths they are not hard coded! In my code I just use paths relative to the R project file for the output folders. The rest is generated by R/Rstudio!

Comment: Then you have to tell R/Rstudio not to hard-code the paths, because hard-coded paths are not going to work.

Comment: How do I do that? by the way the path are not totally hardcoded, otherways it would use the path on my computer, instead the path point to my colleague user on his computer.

Comment: The `/Users/...` is not a Windows path. That looks to me like a Mac path. So that must be in the code somewhere, because it cannot be getting it from the local (Windows) environment. `/Users/<username>` is a Mac OS X directory. It would be most unusual to find this elsewhere, especially on Windows. Even if `LUCILL` is your colleague's username on the Windows box, whatever the Windows equivalent of home is, it isn't going to be `/Users/LUCILL`.

Comment: Ok I agree. But my code is shown in the post. There's nothing about the user path!

Comment: Well, I don't know R. But something is putting it in somewhere. Make sure you are not sharing generated files, of course.

Comment: I checked, C:/Users is a valid windows path. I also got rid of the white space and to be sure I run the code in a new R project in a local folder, to control for possible problems brought by using on Windows a project build on a Mac. Nothing...

Comment: In that case, I apologise for the noise. I didn't know that Windows had `/Users`, too.

Comment: I think the problem is in the generation and retrieval of temporary files. I opened an issue in the Rmarkdown github where I update on my research on the problem. https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/574